# ArrayList removeAll() returning false. any alternatives?

Tags: java, android

I have two ArrayLists and I want to remove all objects of first ArrayList with reference to second ArrayList. I know I can use removeAll() method but it is returning false.Both ArrayLists are of same type. any alternatives of removeAll()

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (successfullyAssigned) {
            ArrayList<CustomDataModel> dataList = adapter.getDataSet();
            Boolean deleted = dataList.removeAll(taskDataList);
            Log.d("LogTag", "deleted ? " + deleted);

            setPreference(getPrefName(), dataList);
        }
  }

 public ArrayList<CustomDataModel> getDataSet() {
    return dataSet;
}

private class AssignTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<CustomDataModel>, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<CustomDataModel> taskDataList;
    Boolean successfullyAssigned;


    @SafeVarargs
    @Override
    protected final Void doInBackground(ArrayList<CustomDataModel>... callData) {
        taskDataList = callData[0];
```

Comment: Could it be returning `false` because it was empty to begin with?

Comment: `removeAll` is returning false because `dataList` and `taskDataList` contain no elements in common.  As @JoeC says, a good bet is that at least one of them is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three reasons this can happen

1. One of the lists is empty.
2. The lists do not have common elements.
3. You did not implement `CustomDataModel.equals()`.

Comment: I was looking for it and yes I realized that I didnt override. equals() in my POJO class... Thanks for the reply